# IIS URL Redirection from main application to sub-application

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am using Windows Server 2008 + IIS. I need the rule as below:

www.mysite.com -> wwww.mysite.com/go

Except: www.mysite.com/come will run **come** application

**go** and **come** are 2 applications (PHP wordpress) run inside the main application (.NET)

Here is rule that I tried but error

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="go" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="wwww.mysite.com/go" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="come" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^come/$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Please define what is "no success". Error code? Any other? Note that you don't even get www correctly (rarely people use four w).

Comment: I got error 503 and redirect loop :(